# How to debug a "Cannot find module" error in Javascript? MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, debugging, dependencies

I have a Typescript project whose `tsconfig.json` file currently looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2020",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "newLine": "lf",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

When I build my project with `tsc` no problems arise. But when I run it with `node dist/server/index.js` I get errors like `Cannot find module 'server/foo/bar' MODULE_NOT_FOUND`.

What tools do developers have to try to debug this?

TypeScript could find the module during transpilation, otherwise it would have failed. Why can't JavaScript find it then?

How can I know where it tried to look for the module? Or any other information that could help the developer figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not usually tools that developers use to resolve issues like this, but knowledge of how their package manager stores and loads packages.

For instance, if you are using `yarn` and its [Plug'n'Play](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp) feature (check whether you have a `.pnp.cjs` file in your project root where your `package.json` is located) then running:

```
yarn node dist/server/index.js
```

will include plug-and-play in node's module loading (refer to the link above for details) and allow packages to be resolved. When typescript code is compiled the `tsc` compiler must also be run under `yarn` to allow modules to be resolved, which is implicitly happening if `tsc` is being run as a script from your `package.json`.